# SQL Server - How can I use a case statement to replace this if in the where clause

Tags: sql-server, if-statement, case, where-clause

Here is my code.  I need to find a way to replicate what this if line would do.
Basically for one of my "codes" I need to only select it if it's length is 11 (some of the old data for that code has a number length of 10 and can't be used)

```
SELECT * FROM 
( SELECT  cast(Left( ZIP, 5) as VARCHAR) as ZIP, 
cast(NUMBER as VARCHAR) as NUMBER,
cast( ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY CODE ORDER BY NEWID() ASC) as VARCHAR) rn 
FROM tbl_MyTable 
WHERE EMAIL is null 
AND CODE is not NULL 
AND CODE != '' 
AND NUMBER not like '%?%' 
AND Date < '1/20/15' 

****AND IF CODE = 'THIS' len(NUMBER) = 11****       

AND ZIP != '43830' ) a WHERE rn = 1
```

Comment: `IF CODE <> 'THIS' or len(NUMBER)<>11` then what you want to do

Answer (score 0):

```
AND CASE WHEN CODE = 'THIS' AND LEN(NUMBER) <> 11 THEN 0 ELSE 1 END = 1
```

The reverse might be more readable to you but be aware that will handle a null CODE as false so it's not precisely the opposite.

```
AND CASE WHEN CODE <> 'THIS' OR LEN(NUMBER) = 11 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END = 1
```